# git merge doesn't seem to merge the second time onwards

Tags: git

We have two branches `origin/master` and `origin/prod`. We do the following to merge changes from master into prod.

```
git clone -b prod <git-url>
git merge origin/master (it merges all data from master into prod)
```

At this juncture, we made some more changes to origin/master.
    We want to pull the additional changes from orign/master using the following command.
    git merge origin/master

But the above command doesn't pull the additional changes from origin/master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd path/to/your/project  
git pull origin master  
git checkout prod  
git merge master
```

or

```
cd path/to/your/project  
git fetch origin master  
git checkout prod  
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: Is it git pull origin master or git pull origin/master?

Comment: @priya it's `git pull origin master` without slash. :)

Comment: How do I commit the changes to the prod. Is it git commit . and git push?

Comment: @priya yes, it is. `git add [your change files]` -> `git cimmit -m "[your commit message]"` -> `git push origin prod`(if you just use `git push`, it will push all branches that you pushed before).

Comment: What command should I use to add/commit all files which have been merged, since there would be a lot of merged files. I don't want to selectively add/commit the changes.

Comment: @priya run `git add .` at your root of prject, or you can do some mapping: `git add *.m`, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5840/discussion-between-priya-and-kjuly)

Answer (score 4):

You should do `git pull origin master`, or do `git fetch master && git merge origin/master`.

The command `git merge origin/master` is a local operation that just uses the state of the "origin/master" branch on YOUR repository; it does not contact any remote repositories.  You need to fetch or pull to do that.

Comment: How do I commit the changes to the prod. Is it git commit . and git push?